# GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.insert failed with error: Dataset id is missing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I am struggling to understand why this Google Appscript code doesn't work. The error I get is dataset id missing, but I think I have referenced the dataset ID in the right place. I have checked and the id is correct.

```
function exportToBigQuery() {
  // Replace with your Google Cloud Project ID
  var projectId = 'project-id';
  
  // Replace with your BigQuery Dataset ID and Table ID
  var datasetId = 'project-id.external_data';
  var tableId = 'project-id.external_data.workload_grouping';

  // Get the active spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Get the active sheet
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  // Get the data in the sheet as a 2D array
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Prepare the data for BigQuery
  var jsonData = data.map(function (row) {
    return { data: row };
  });

  // Create a BigQuery table reference
  var tableReference = BigQuery.newTableReference(projectId, datasetId, tableId);

  // Define the schema for your table (change as needed)
  var tableSchema = [
    { name: 'data', type: 'STRING' },
  ];

  // Create a BigQuery job to insert the data
  var jobConfig = {
    load: {
      destinationTable: tableReference,
      schema: { fields: tableSchema },
      sourceFormat: 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
      createDisposition: 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
      writeDisposition: 'WRITE_APPEND',
    },
  };

  var job = {
    datasetId: 'sam-test-project-07-23.external_data',
    configuration: jobConfig,
  };

  // Convert JSON data to a Blob
  var jsonDataBlob = Utilities.newBlob(jsonData.map(JSON.stringify).join('\n'), 'application/json');

  // Insert the data
  BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, jsonDataBlob)

  Logger.log('Data has been exported to BigQuery.');
}
```

Problem occurs at the 'Insert the data' line. Any help would be much appreciated!

Objective of this code is to upload everything in a google sheet o bigquery